# How to order columns in a matrix based on final column values?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to reorder existing matrices in R based on final column values but I can't seem to find a solution. I've tried order(), but no luck. I'm obviously overlooking something. Any ideas? For instance, let's say we create a matrix with 5 columns of data:

```
> a <-matrix(100+rnorm(50),10,5)
> a
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
 [1,] 101.26878  99.36657  99.32874  99.46449 101.46698
 [2,] 102.28284 102.62506 100.21430 100.54780 100.14608
 [3,]  99.25180 100.93911 101.31455  99.92939  99.87537
 [4,]  99.69423  99.17830  99.20230  99.42162 100.70614
 [5,]  99.03745  99.95904 100.85773  98.39691 100.84777
 [6,] 100.09040 101.66841  98.73320  97.41576  99.36144
 [7,]  99.94181 100.18932 101.26947  99.81551  99.30574
 [8,]  99.15694  98.24990  98.81500  99.26529 100.72547
 [9,] 100.52822  99.43562 101.73370  98.32482  99.30498
[10,] 100.37140  99.54621  99.37048  99.43794 101.28328
```

How would I reorder the columns based on the final values and save the results in a matrix? For instance, column [,5] has the highest final value (101.28328) so it would be listed first, in the extreme left; column [,1] would be second, and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
a[,order(a[nrow(a),])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone will beat me to this, but.. (this is far from optimized code)

```
maxes <- pmax(a[,1],a[,2],a[,3],a[,4],a[,5])
colorder <- order(maxes)
a.order <- a[,colorder]
```

Edit -- this answer finds the max anywhere in the column, which is not was asked for.  Frank's answer is correct.